# BarLegend with unequally spaced contours

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I would like to get a `BarLegend` similar to this one with **unequally** spaced contours:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
colors = {RGBColor[0.9529411764705882, 0.9686274509803922, 0.9215686274509803], 
RGBColor[0.9529411764705882, 0.9137254901960784, 0.8156862745098039], 
RGBColor[0.9803921568627451, 0.788235294117647, 0.7607843137254902], 
RGBColor[0.9568627450980391, 0.6196078431372549, 0.796078431372549], 
RGBColor[0.8235294117647058, 0.49019607843137253`, 0.8941176470588235], 
RGBColor[0.592156862745098, 0.4784313725490196, 0.984313725490196],
RGBColor[0.3333333333333333, 0.6, 0.9568627450980391],
RGBColor[0.16470588235294117`, 0.807843137254902, 0.7686274509803921], 
RGBColor[0.16862745098039217`, 0.9725490196078431, 0.43529411764705883`], 
RGBColor[0.38431372549019605`, 0.9215686274509803, 0.11764705882352941`], 
RGBColor[0.6078431372549019, 0.6470588235294118, 0.00392156862745098], 
RGBColor[0.6941176470588235, 0.33725490196078434`, 0.07058823529411765], 
RGBColor[0.615686274509804, 0.10980392156862745`, 0.22352941176470587`], 
RGBColor[0.4235294117647059, 0.01568627450980392, 0.34901960784313724`], 
RGBColor[0.21568627450980393`, 0.0392156862745098, 0.3764705882352941], 
RGBColor[0.07450980392156863, 0.10196078431372549`, 0.29411764705882354`], 
RGBColor[0.023529411764705882`, 0.12549019607843137`, 0.16470588235294117`],
RGBColor[0.027450980392156862`, 0.07450980392156863, 0.054901960784313725`]};

values = {0, 0.764828, 0.906574, 1.07459, 1.27374, 1.50981, 1.78962, 2.1213, 2.51444, 
2.98044, 3.53281, 4.18754, 4.96362, 5.88354, 6.97394, 8.26642, 9.79844, 11.6144, 14.8};

pairs = Partition[Riffle[values, colors],2];
```

The following piece of code provides `BarLegend` with continously varying colours :

```
Contbar = BarLegend[{Blend[pairs, #1] &, {0, 14.8}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

I tried "discontinous" version of `BarLegend` with visible contours:

```
Discbar = BarLegend[{Blend[pairs, #1] &, {0, 14.8}},values, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

but now the contours are equally spaced, which is not what I wanted.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe build it from scratch:

```
d1 = Module[{a=Partition[Insert[pairs[[All, 1]], values[[-1]], -1], 2, 1]},
Table[{pairs[[i, 2]],Rectangle[{a[[i, 1]], 0}, {a[[i, 2]], 1}]}, {i, 1, Length[a]}]];
```

and visualise adjusting tick sizes (if you want to!):

```
 barLeg = Graphics[d1, Axes -> {True, False}, PlotRange -> {{0, 14}, All}, BaseStyle -> 18, 
 ImageSize -> 700, Ticks -> {Join[{#, Column[{"", #}, Spacings -> 0], -0.02, 
 {Black, Thick}}& /@ Range[0, 14, 4], Table[{i, "", -0.01, {Black, Thick}}, {i, 1, 14, 1}]], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
colors = {RGBColor[0.9529411764705882, 0.9686274509803922, 
    0.9215686274509803], 
   RGBColor[0.9529411764705882, 0.9137254901960784, 
    0.8156862745098039], 
   RGBColor[0.9803921568627451, 0.788235294117647, 
    0.7607843137254902], 
   RGBColor[0.9568627450980391, 0.6196078431372549, 
    0.796078431372549], 
   RGBColor[0.8235294117647058, 0.49019607843137253`, 
    0.8941176470588235], 
   RGBColor[0.592156862745098, 0.4784313725490196, 0.984313725490196],
    RGBColor[0.3333333333333333, 0.6, 0.9568627450980391], 
   RGBColor[0.16470588235294117`, 0.807843137254902, 
    0.7686274509803921], 
   RGBColor[0.16862745098039217`, 0.9725490196078431, 
    0.43529411764705883`], 
   RGBColor[0.38431372549019605`, 0.9215686274509803, 
    0.11764705882352941`], 
   RGBColor[0.6078431372549019, 0.6470588235294118, 
    0.00392156862745098], 
   RGBColor[0.6941176470588235, 0.33725490196078434`, 
    0.07058823529411765], 
   RGBColor[0.615686274509804, 0.10980392156862745`, 
    0.22352941176470587`], 
   RGBColor[0.4235294117647059, 0.01568627450980392, 
    0.34901960784313724`], 
   RGBColor[0.21568627450980393`, 0.0392156862745098, 
    0.3764705882352941], 
   RGBColor[0.07450980392156863, 0.10196078431372549`, 
    0.29411764705882354`], 
   RGBColor[0.023529411764705882`, 0.12549019607843137`, 
    0.16470588235294117`], 
   RGBColor[0.027450980392156862`, 0.07450980392156863, 
    0.054901960784313725`]};

values = {0, 0.764828, 0.906574, 1.07459, 1.27374, 1.50981, 1.78962, 
   2.1213, 2.51444, 2.98044, 3.53281, 4.18754, 4.96362, 5.88354, 
   6.97394, 8.26642, 9.79844, 11.6144, 14.8};

p = Transpose[{Partition[values, 2, 1], colors}]
r = ({Last@#, First@First@# <= x <= Last@First@#} & /@ p);
cf[x_] = Piecewise[r]
```

Taking advantage of a few undocumented options:

```
BarLegend[{cf, MinMax[values]}
 , LegendLayout -> "Row"
 , LegendMarkerSize -> {400, 30}
 , Ticks -> Transpose[{Range[Sequence @@ MinMax@values, 4]
    , ToString /@ Range[Sequence @@ MinMax@values, 4]
    }]
 , FrameStyle -> White
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work for me. I got purely black and white 'BarLegend'. I am using Mathematica 12.1.

Comment: @Moonwalk, I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.